# Drop rows which column A don't have at least X unique values in column B, pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
user_id item   category rank
-------------------------------
user_1  item1  categoryA  1
user_1  item2  categoryA  2
user_1  item3  categoryA  3
user_1  item4  categoryD  4
user_1  item5  categoryD  5
user_2  item6  categoryB  1
user_2  item7  categoryB  2
user_2  item8  categoryB  3
user_2  item9  categoryA  4
user_2  item10 categoryE  5
user_2  item11 categoryE  6
user_3  item6  categoryB  1
user_3  item7  categoryB  2
user_3  item8  categoryB  3
user_3  item9  categoryA  4
user_3  item10 categoryE  5
user_3  item11 categoryE  6
```

In which I have recommendations of items for users. I'm expected to have 6 recommendations per user and I would like to count how many users have 6 (user 2 and user3 in this example) and how many users have left than 6 (user1).

I would also to be able to drop those who don't have at least 6 (user1).

Which is the most optimal pyspark way of doing this? Rankoverwindow sum of ranks? and checking if that value is 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a left semi join with `user_id`s that have at least `rank >=6`:

```
df1 = df.join(
    df.filter("rank >= 6").select("user_id").distinct(),
    ["user_id"],
    "left_semi"
)

df1.show()
#+-------+------+---------+----+
#|user_id|  item| category|rank|
#+-------+------+---------+----+
#| user_2| item6|categoryB|   1|
#| user_2| item7|categoryB|   2|
#| user_2| item8|categoryB|   3|
#| user_2| item9|categoryA|   4|
#| user_2|item10|categoryE|   5|
#| user_2|item11|categoryE|   6|
#| user_3| item6|categoryB|   1|
#| user_3| item7|categoryB|   2|
#| user_3| item8|categoryB|   3|
#| user_3| item9|categoryA|   4|
#| user_3|item10|categoryE|   5|
#| user_3|item11|categoryE|   6|
#+-------+------+---------+----+
```

Or `max_rank >= 6` over window :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df1 = df.withColumn("max_rn", F.max("rank").over(Window.partitionBy("user_id")))\
    .filter("max_rn >= 6").drop("max_rn")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter using a count over each user:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'cnt', 
    F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('user_id'))
).filter('cnt >= 6')

df2.show()
+-------+------+---------+----+---+
|user_id|  item| category|rank|cnt|
+-------+------+---------+----+---+
| user_2| item6|categoryB|   1|  6|
| user_2| item7|categoryB|   2|  6|
| user_2| item8|categoryB|   3|  6|
| user_2| item9|categoryA|   4|  6|
| user_2|item10|categoryE|   5|  6|
| user_2|item11|categoryE|   6|  6|
| user_3| item6|categoryB|   1|  6|
| user_3| item7|categoryB|   2|  6|
| user_3| item8|categoryB|   3|  6|
| user_3| item9|categoryA|   4|  6|
| user_3|item10|categoryE|   5|  6|
| user_3|item11|categoryE|   6|  6|
+-------+------+---------+----+---+
```